# Unable to get sphinx to execute through PHP via SSH - connection faild errno 111

Tags: php, ssh, full-text-search, sphinx

I've setup spinx as followed on a Linux server - the indexing has worked via SSH I am now trying to connect the sphinx to the PHP on the 'front-end' of the website

Here is the search.php file I am trying to use
http://pastebin.com/Q27dK6Kq

Each time I run the php search.php from the command line I get the following error:
Query failed: connection to 195.xxx.xxx.xxx:3312 failed (errno=111, msg=Connectioned refused). Any ideas how to fix this?

Below is my Sphinx config file

sphinx.conf

#

## Minimal Sphinx configuration sample (clean, simple, functional)

#

source article
{
        type                    = mysql

```
    sql_host                = localhost
    sql_user                = username
    sql_pass                = randompassword
    sql_db                  = my_database
    sql_port                = 3306  # optional, default is 3306

    sql_query               = SELECT ID, Title, Description from articles

    # sql_attr_uint         = group_id
    # sql_attr_timestamp    = date_added

    sql_query_info          = SELECT * FROM articles WHERE ID=$id
```

}

index test1
{
        source                  = article
        path                    = data/test1
        docinfo                 = extern
        charset_type            = sbcs
}

index testrt
{
        type                    = rt
        rt_mem_limit            = 32M

```
    path                    = data/testrt
    charset_type            = utf-8

    rt_field                = Title
    rt_field                = Description
```

}

indexer
{
        mem_limit               = 32M
}

searchd
{
        listen                  = 9312
        listen                  = 3312:mysql41
        log                     = /var/log/searchd.log
        query_log               = /var/log/query.log
}

Comment: UPDATE:
I noticed the ports were incorrect & have fixed these - I now get the following error:

`Query failed: failed to read searchd response (status=2613, ver=11824, len=775501357, read=74).`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed - for some reason the installation got corrupted and was missing a single file. #weird